# How to insert data to sql using SQLSRV Prepared statement

Tags: php, insert, sqlsrv

I have tried everything to get this code work and i am really stuck. As far as i can see everything is as it should be. I could be missing something really easy but i cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('europe/london');
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);

require 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $cutdate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $split = explode(" ",$cutdate); 
    $dateformat = $split[0];
    $date = str_replace("/", "-", $dateformat);
    $dayofweek = date_format(new DateTime($date),'l');
    $monthofyear = date_format(new DateTime($date),'F');
    $yearof = date_format(new DateTime($date),'Y');
    $weekcommencingform = Date('d-m-Y', strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($date)));
    $weekcommencing = str_replace("-", "/", $weekcommencingform);

    $inc = $_POST['inc'];
    $status = 'Open';
    $start = $_POST['start_date'];
    $incday = $dayofweek;
    $incweek = $weekcommencing;
    $incmonth = $monthofyear;
    $incyear = $yearof;
    $channel = $_POST['channel'];
    $journey = $_POST['journey'];
    $application = $_POST['application'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $opened_by = $_SESSION["user"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[incidents] 
                        (inc, status, act_start_date, start_date, 
                        inc_day, inc_week, inc_month, inc_year, 
                        opened_by, priority, system, category, 
                        channel, journey, description) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $params = array( &$inc, &$status, &$start, &$start, 
                    &$incday, &$incweek, &$incmonth, &$incyear, 
                    &$opened_by, &$priority, &$application, &$category, 
                    &$channel, &$journey, &$description);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql, $params);

if ($stmt) {  
    echo "Row successfully inserted";  
} else {  
    echo "Row insertion failed";  
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```

Comment: Got any error messages for us to look at? Or maybe something more than a block of code

Comment: A look at `connect.php` might be useful as well

Comment: the error is This page isn’t working
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500. I know its not the connect as it works find for some update queries i have

Comment: Its strange as i have error reporting on as well.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: nothing, its really strange as its producing this error instead of the error reporting one

Comment: see the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the below answer below. It was still doing the same thing until i added } below the execute.

Comment: Now it runs and says row inserted however when i check my table its still blank. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `sqlsrv_query` doesn't prepare, it simply sends the SQL for immediate execution. It does NOT support prepared statements so you will have to have sanitized data included inline. To use prepared statements you have to fix your code and change

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql, $params);
if ($stmt) {  
    echo "Row successfully inserted";  
} else {  
    echo "Row insertion failed";  
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```

to

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($con, $sql, $params);
if (sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false) {
    echo "Row insertion failed";  
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
} else echo "Row successfully inserted";
```

Here is documentation for [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) and [sqlsrv_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php)

Comment: Ohhh for heavans sake... How did I miss that DUH!

Comment: Thanks for the below answer below. It was still doing the same thing until i added } at the bottom. It now says row inserted as it should however when i check the table its still blank

Comment: I have updated my answer, as your code for checking success of insert was also checking for `$stmt` when it should be checking for the result of `sqlsrv_execute`

Comment: Thanks again. Havnt been able to test yet. ran into another issue with date formats Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. i dont suppose you know anything about this?

Comment: Ask another question about it. I may know sthg on those as well

Comment: @jRogers please accept this then ask another question on those conversions

Comment: Are you sure this answer is correct? I report from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15) : `The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.` Can you please explain why and on what basis you say that sqlsrv_query does not prepare? Even the PHP manual page reports `sqlsrv_query — Prepares and executes a query`

Comment: I'm not sure why I had written it like that, it was 2 years ago. It (docs might also have been updated) might have changed since then but the code was working